# Стоит ли использовать TOP для обнаружения утечек памяти?

Tags: c, память, unix

Всем добрый день!
Хотелось бы услышать мнения на тему, стоит ли использовать TOP для выявления утечек или есть более удобные средства (речь не о локализации ошибки, а о способе быстрого выявления того, что они есть). Проверяю работу своего демона под TOP - вижу что с каждым новым присоединенным клиентом обьем памяти в графе RES возрастает, и не возвращается к исходному варианту когда клиент отвалился. Пыталась найти истоник при пошаговой отладке, но вижу только, что после выполнения *free()* обьем памяти отображаемый в TOP не уменьшается или уменьшается незначительно, несравнимо с изначальным приростом.

Comment: GC не? Я [этот](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) юзаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, top для этого совершенно не подходит. Кроме того он может неверно отображать реальное потребление памяти тем или иным процессом (если нужен пруф, то поищите на эту тему).

А для поиска утечек в ваших прилжениях можно использовать [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)  или любой другой [профилировщик](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

[Эта](http://www.xakep.ru/post/55102/) статья также может быть полезной.

Comment: @1101_debian, Валгриндом пользуюсь время от времени с переменным успехом, он не часто обновляется для freebsd. Хотелось бы просто чем-то реальное потребление памяти в динамике увидеть.